# Flex container and float, which is the correct width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, css-shapes

I've got a document like this:

```css
main {
  width: 200px;
}

main>div {
  display: flex;
}

main>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}

main>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
  height: 20px;
}

main>aside {
  shape-outside: content-box;
  background: pink;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

main>aside:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

main>aside:nth-child(even) {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <aside></aside>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

where I want to push some floating elements down by a given offset. This works in Firefox 63 but not in Chrome 69, and I wonder what is the correct behaviour, and if any workarounds are known.

So I want the main content to flow around just the content area of the aside, and ignore the top margin, even though the div comes after the aside in the document. To achieve this, I use css shapes to make the main content flow around the content box. To make each item (and this is where my doubt is) take only the available width taking into account floating elements, I set display: flex. In Firefox this makes only the divs next to the aside content box be 50%. Is this behaviour documented somewhere, that flex containers don't overlap with floating elements like block elements do?

Chrome does not honor the css shape and makes every div in the main until after the last aside half the width when the divs have `display: flex`.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQjOqp

Comment: Is the use of `aside:nth-child()` and not `aside:nth-of-type()` selector intentional? Both `aside` elements are currently captured by the `odd` rule because they're counted together with `div`s.

Comment: Yeah,  `nth-of-type` would be a better fit, but it's just to show that all the `aside`s and `div`s can be of different heights.

Comment: I think this isn't a well-defined browser behavior because `shape-outside` is for wrapping inline content. Could you detail more what you want your actual page to look/behave like? Your example for instance could easily be replicated with a grid.

Comment: @tagurit I'm trying to bottom-align a floated element (the asides) to one of the non-floated elements (the divs). Both the number and size of floated and non-floated elements is not predictable and depends on generated content. With the above technique I am using javascript to find the correct offset so it bottom aligns to a given div. It's important white-space above and below the floated elements is filled where possible with divs extending. The content inside the divs can't be layed out with just `display: inline`. Ideally I can use `display: flex` like above.

Comment: Will probably have to go for the second best option, which uses `position: absolute` and resizes individual divs with javascript.